# Displaying letters of this alphabet

Tags: fonts, symbols

Is there anything I can do (like a font (or whatever) I can install) in order for these symbols to display properly?

```
o͘ O͘ ⁿ

á é í ó ó͘ ú ḿ ń Á É Í Ó Ó͘ Ú Ḿ Ń

à è ì ò ò͘ ù m̀ ǹ À È Ì Ò Ò͘ Ù M̀ Ǹ

â ê î ô ô͘ û m̂ n̂ Â Ê Î Ô Ô͘ Û M̂ N̂

ā ē ī ō ō͘ ū m̄ n̄ Ā Ē Ī Ō Ō͘ Ū M̄ N̄

a̍ e̍ i̍ o̍ o̍͘ u̍ m̍ n̍ A̍ E̍ I̍ O̍ O̍͘ U̍ M̍ N̍

ă ĕ ĭ ŏ ŏ͘ ŭ m̆ n̆ Ă Ĕ Ĭ Ŏ Ŏ͘ Ŭ M̆ N̆
```

Comment: General tip: adding `\tracinglostchars=2` near the top of your document will warn you when you try to use a character that your font does not contain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably several fonts that have all of these characters, on Windows at least you can use Arial for example:

This is generated with xelatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars2
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

o͘ O͘ ⁿ

á é í ó ó͘ ú ḿ ń Á É Í Ó Ó͘ Ú Ḿ Ń

à è ì ò ò͘ ù m̀ ǹ À È Ì Ò Ò͘ Ù M̀ Ǹ

â ê î ô ô͘ û m̂ n̂ Â Ê Î Ô Ô͘ Û M̂ N̂

ā ē ī ō ō͘ ū m̄ n̄ Ā Ē Ī Ō Ō͘ Ū M̄ N̄

a̍ e̍ i̍ o̍ o̍͘ u̍ m̍ n̍ A̍ E̍ I̍ O̍ O̍͘ U̍ M̍ N̍

ă ĕ ĭ ŏ ŏ͘ ŭ m̆ n̆ Ă Ĕ Ĭ Ŏ Ŏ͘ Ŭ M̆ N̆
\end{document}
```

Or with Linix Libertine (which is in Tex live)

[image]

with the following change

```
%\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmainfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}
```

Comment: Don’t use Linux Libertine anymore, though, use Libertinus instead.

Comment: What can be wrong if when I'm trying to follow (for example) "pe̍h" with ")", I get "pe̍)h" instead of "pe̍h)"?

Comment: @user181940 you have not posted any code that anyone can debug. Impossible to guess

Comment: Let me back up a little. I just copy-pasted your (first) code to Overleaf and compiled it (using xelatex) and that's what I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/crCyv.png ...
As for what I described in the previous comment, it was happening with the same preable as in your code and the text  "pe̍h" between \begin{document} and \end{document}.

Comment: @user181940 Arial is a windows font it will not be available on overleaf you must have got errors in the log?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmm, but it worked earlier today in overleaf. I didn't use exactly your preamble (I had some additional stuff there), but now that is also not showing up correctly. The log says "No errors, good job!"

Comment: @user181940 you get no error but you get dozens of missing glyph warnings. You do find an arial font at /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf  but that is an old version (probably the last version Microsoft shipped with a licence for non windows use) which has fewer characters than the opentype arial in windows.  so the basic part of my answer holds you need a font with the characters. Try linux libertine or libertinus

Answer (score 5):

For example font LinuxLibertine supports all theese characters. You need nothing install, LinuxLibertine is part of TeXlive or Linux operation system.

Following example uses OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[libertine]

o͘ O͘ ⁿ

á é í ó ó ú ḿ ń Á É Í Ó Ó͘ Ú Ḿ Ń

à è ì ò ò ù m̀ ǹ À È Ì Ò Ò Ù M̀ Ǹ

â ê î ô ô û m̂ n̂ Â Ê Î Ô Ô Û M̂ N̂

ā ē ī ō ō ū m̄ n̄ Ā Ē Ī Ō Ō Ū M̄ N̄

a̍ e̍ i̍ o̍ o u̍ m̍ n̍ A̍ E̍ I̍ O̍ O U̍ M̍ N̍

ă ĕ ĭ ŏ ŏ ŭ m̆ n̆ Ă Ĕ Ĭ Ŏ Ŏ Ŭ M̆ N̆

\end
```

Comment: ah +1 hope you don't mind if I give a latex example with this font (didn't like just giving a windows example)

Comment: Is [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-the-free-linux-libertine-fonts-in-latex/rhcnysrwsjmn) essentially the same what you suggested? I tried it, but I'm getting errors like "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ͘ (U+0358)".

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to be (partially) working with libertinus. [But there are some problems...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592651/space-appears-in-the-wrong-place)

Comment: @user181940 no, this is not essentially the same what I suggested. My example is based on OpTeX which has nothing to do with LaTeX. "Package inputenc Error" is only LaTeX problem. And your second problem depends only on the software you are using when you are editing the source of the document.