# Displaying IPA symbols in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, linguistics

I'm trying to use IPA symbols as well as letters described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573354/displaying-letters-of-this-alphabet) in a beamer presentation, but it doesn't seem to work.

For the alphabet described in the link I have

```
\tracinglostchars2
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

For IPA, I tried to use the following as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36542/how-to-use-phonetic-ipa-characters-in-latex):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}
```

But not all IPA symbols are showing up. Here are some that don't:

```
ɕʰ sʰ ʑ  ɾ  k̚  t̚  p̚  ʔ pʰ tʰ kʰ
```

How to make them display?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\tracinglostchars2
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}   
\author{} 
\date{} 

\frame{\frametitle{lí-hó} 

ɕʰ sʰ ʑ  ɾ  k̚  t̚  p̚  ʔ pʰ tʰ kʰ

lí kám ē-hiáu khòaⁿ chiah ê jī
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the preamble, add `\usefonttheme{serif}` to use serif font. Otherwise, you can try `\setsansfont{Doulos SIL}`.

Comment: Also, don't use `\usepackage{fontspec}` more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve run into a gotcha with `beamer` and `fontspec`  The `\setmainfont` command in `fontspec` sets the *serif* family, but `beamer` changes the default font to the *sans-serif* family.  So, your document is not using the font you selected with `\setmainfont`.

If you check the warning messages `\tracinglostchars2` gives you on the console, you’ll see it telling you that the current font is Latin Modern Sans 10 and it does not have those characters.  That’s the default sans-serif font `fontspec` loads, and the MWE never changed it.

You have a few options.  One is to load a font family that has these symbols, such as DejaVu or Libertinus.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}   
\author{} 
\date{} 

\frame{\frametitle{lí-hó} 

ɕʰ sʰ ʑ  ɾ  k̚  t̚  p̚  ʔ pʰ tʰ kʰ

lí kám ē-hiáu khòaⁿ chiah ê jī
}

\end{document}
```

This will use DejaVu Sans by default, but let you use `\rmfamily`, `\ttfamily` or `\textrm` to switch to serif or monospaced fonts that also have those symbols.  Remember to check for warnings about missing characters!

Another solution, which Alan Xiang brought up in the comments, is to add the line `\usefonttheme{serif}` to your preamble.  This will make `\setmainfont` work the way you expect.

Finally, you can set the missing Unicode characters active and supply them from another font.  This example uses the free version of URW Charter as the main font, but takes all the linguistic symbols it’s missing from Charis SIL (which is based on Charter).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\setmainfont{XCharter}
\newfontfamily\ipafont{Charis SIL}[
  Ligatures=Common,
  Scale=MatchLowercase ]

\newunicodechar{^^^^0255}{{\ipafont\symbol{"0255}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^027e}{{\ipafont\symbol{"027E}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^0291}{{\ipafont\symbol{"0291}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^0294}{{\ipafont\symbol{"0294}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^02b0}{{\ipafont\symbol{"02B0}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^031a}{{\ipafont\symbol{"031A}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^207f}{{\ipafont\symbol{"207F}}}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}   
\author{} 
\date{} 

\frame{\frametitle{lí-hó} 

ɕʰ sʰ ʑ  ɾ  k̚  t̚  p̚  ʔ pʰ tʰ kʰ

lí kám ē-hiáu khòaⁿ chiah ê jī
}

\end{document}
```