# Space appears in the wrong place

Tags: fonts, overleaf, libertinus

Following comments I received in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573354/displaying-letters-of-this-alphabet), I'm trying to use `libertinus` font (in Overleaf).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\tracinglostchars2
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

hō͘ lí

\end{document}
```

At first glance everything seems to be working fine, but when I place the cursor between `l` and `í` in the word `lí` and press "space", I would expect to get `l í` but instead I'm getting  `lí` (i.e, the space is added not between the letters, but before the word). When I delete `hō͘` before `lí` and repeat the above, everything seems to be working fine, I'm getting `l í`. Similar bugs happen many other cases. What's the problem with this?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue you describe on a Mac running MacOS 11.2.3 "Big Sur", MacTeX2021, and either TeXworks 0.6.6 or TeXshop 4.6.2. It would appear that the issue you've encountered is specific to the editing software employed by Overleaf. Have you contacted Overleaf's Help Desk and asked them for advice? I hear the LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: If you're compiling with `xelatex`, you don't want the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` line. Without this line, I have no problems and can put spaces between the l and í fine.

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean on Overleaf. I can reproduce this under Chromium. It's OK under Firefox though.

Comment: I contacted Overleaf's Help Desk as per @Mico's advice, and here's part of their reply: "This cursor displacement problem seems to be due to the underlying source editor that Overleaf uses (the ace editor) and its support for Chromium. The dev team is aware of the issue - on our end we hope to address it in a general editor update (hopefully in the near future), although conceivably the problem could be fixed in the underlying editor before then."